# How can I retrieve comments of all posts in posts list page

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is: I want to show the user number of comments he has for each post.
I have a posts manager and I can't get the id of each post.

```
public function myposts(Post $post,Pcomment $pcomment){
    if(Auth::check()){
        $agent = new Agent();
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id', '-ASC')->paginate(5);
        $pcomments = $pcomment->where('post_id',"=", $post->id)->get();
        return view('posts.myposts',compact('posts','agent','pcomments'));
    }else{
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: `-ASC` is that right?

Comment: Have you setup relationships between the models?

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup the relationship between the models correctly like so

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

then you can just run the following to get all user comments on a post

```
$user_comments = $post->comments()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

If you just want a count then do the following

```
$user_comment_count = $post->comments()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, I hope this will help you

> **Post.php (Model)**

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

---

> **Controller**

`->withCount('comments')` function is used to count comments for each post.

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->withCount('comments')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id', '-ASC')->paginate(5);
```